# Javascript selector to select field in parent window from popup window

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a parent HTML window and a pop up window. I want to access fields in parent window when I click a button inside popup.

I have tried this but it doesn't work from popup:

```
top.document.getElementById('itemCounter').innerHTML = '1';
```

It throws the following exception:

```
Javascript selector - `top.document.getElementById('itemCounter')` returns null from popup screen but return object `top.document.getElementById('itemCounter')` from parent screen.
```

I am opening popup using window.open.

**Does anyone know how to access field in parent window from pop?**

Thanks

Comment: Can you write the line that will open popup window? I'll need that for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `top` and `parent` will only work with IFRAME popups. If you open a whole new window with `window.open()`, you'll need to use `opener` to access the page which opened your popup. So, try:

```
opener.document.getElementById('itemCounter').innerHTML = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the parent of the pop-up window by using the following code - `this.parent`. This should return you the window object of the parent. You can use that object further for more manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
alert(window.opener...);
```

Use something like `window.opener.document.getElementById('id')`. I use it sometimes to see if it is the correct parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the document.getElementById() from the Opener object rather than top object.

```
popupWinOpener.document.getElementById('itemCounter').innerHTML = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved. I used -

window.opener.top.document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = '1';

I wanted to access object in iFrame in parent window. Thanks all